# Select non zero rows in DAX, power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data

| e_code | hours |
| --- | --- |
| 223 | 4.5 |
| 443 | 0 |
| 5543 | 33.6 |
| 098 | 2 |
| 44 | 0 |
| 21143 | 6.6 |
| 266743 |  |

i want to store those e_code in a new column in power bi by writing a dax code which have non zero hours and exclude blank like

| e_code |
| --- |
| 223 |
| 5543 |
| 098 |
| 21143 |

please help me to get my desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Table = GROUPBY ( FILTER ( '_t', '_t'[hours] <> BLANK () ), _t[e_code] )
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

use this formula :

```
Table =
CALCULATETABLE ( 
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'yourTableName', 
        "e_code", 
        'yourTableName'[e_code]
    ),
    'yourTableName'[hours] > 0
)
```